# C# Copy / Paste with different shortcuts

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I would like to create a global listener for keyboard input that will allow users to copy and paste data into the clipboard with their own user defined shortcuts. I will demonstrate what I need with an example.

Say I am a user who wants to copy three different numbers on three different text boxes within internet explorer. The user highlights the first text box and presses alt-1, does the same with alt-2 for the second and alt-3 for the third. For each shortcut, clipboard data is copied into my application in different fields. Any ideas as to how I can approach this?

This is a c# winforms application developed in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx

This is a global keyboard hook that will work even when your application has no focus.
It wraps native dll's though but there is no other way around it if you want a global hook I think.

Comment: thanks for that, I 've just been playing with the code. Any idea as to how I can combine the Alt button with 1 for example?

Comment: Hi, you should be able to send flags to the native methods if any modifierkeys are pressed.

Comment: Thanks I just tried adding an if statement with Control.ModifierKeys. That seems to work. Someone at the bottom of the page mentions that there can be problems with that code. Any idea about that?

Comment: Sorry no, I've used it a bit for writing keytriggers for macro programs for games and such and it has always worked flawelessly for me.

Comment: Hmmmm tricky, I want to use it for an enterprise application and it makes wonder how reliable it will be. Thanks anyway, I will use this code as a start and then look further.